# MapKit help. Can't get my location to show up first

Tags: ios, geolocation, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I want to develop a map that shows my location and has pins of other locations on the map.

I've gotten the map to show up and the pins to show up too, it also locates me but it doesn't zoom into my location first. How can I get it to show my location first?  When I open up the mapview it just shows the last pin I put into the code. 
Here is my code.

mapview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>




@interface mapview : UIViewController {

    MKMapView *mapview1;


}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletMKMapView *mapview1;

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)getlocation;

@end
```

mapview.m

```
#import "mapview.h"
#import "NewClass.h"

@implementation mapview

@synthesize mapview1;

-(IBAction)getlocation {

    mapview1.showsUserLocation = YES;

}



-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
    switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mapview1.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            mapview1.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            mapview1.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];

        [mapview1 setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapview1 setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [mapview1 setScrollEnabled:YES];

        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
        region.center.latitude = 39.956907;
        region.center.longitude = -75.610229;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
        [mapview1 setRegion:region animated:YES];


        NewClass *ann = [[NewClass alloc] init];
        ann.title = @"Vigil Location";
        ann.subtitle = @"Planned Parenthood of Chester County";
        ann.coordinate = region.center;
        [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann];


    MKCoordinateRegion region1 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region1.center.latitude = 40.042819;
    region1.center.longitude = -75.373776;
    region1.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region1.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region1 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann1 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann1.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann1.subtitle = @"Planned Parenthood of Bryn Mawr";
    ann1.coordinate = region1.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann1];

    MKCoordinateRegion region2 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region2.center.latitude = 40.18295;
    region2.center.longitude = -75.450163;
    region2.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region2.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region2 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann2 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann2.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann2.subtitle = @"Planned Parenthood Collegeville";
    ann2.coordinate = region2.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann2];

    MKCoordinateRegion region3 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region3.center.latitude = 40.120772;
    region3.center.longitude = -75.118181;
    region3.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region3.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region3 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann3 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann3.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann3.subtitle = @"Abington Memorial Hospital";
    ann3.coordinate = region3.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann3];

    MKCoordinateRegion region4 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region4.center.latitude = 39.95361;
    region4.center.longitude = -75.15267;
    region4.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region4.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region4 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann4 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann4.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann4.subtitle = @"Philadelphia Women's Center";
    ann4.coordinate = region4.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann4];

    MKCoordinateRegion region5 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region5.center.latitude = 39.910566;
    region5.center.longitude = -75.014111;
    region5.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region5.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region5 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann5 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann5.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann5.subtitle = @"Cherry Hill Women's Center";
    ann5.coordinate = region5.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann5];

    MKCoordinateRegion region6 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region6.center.latitude = 39.74285;
    region6.center.longitude = -75.550838;
    region6.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region6.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region6 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann6 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann6.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann6.subtitle = @"Planned Parenthood of Wilmington";
    ann6.coordinate = region6.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann6];

    MKCoordinateRegion region7 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region7.center.latitude = 40.03754;
    region7.center.longitude = -76.300828;
    region7.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region7.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region7 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann7 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann7.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann7.subtitle = @"Planned Parenthood of Lancaster";
    ann7.coordinate = region7.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann7];

    MKCoordinateRegion region8 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region8.center.latitude = 40.333819;
    region8.center.longitude = -75.93019;
    region8.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region8.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region8 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann8 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann8.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann8.subtitle = @"Planned Parenthood of Reading";
    ann8.coordinate = region8.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann8];

    MKCoordinateRegion region9 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region9.center.latitude = 40.67246;
    region9.center.longitude = -75.375397;
    region9.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region9.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region9 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann9 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann9.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann9.subtitle = @"Planned Parenthood of Allentown";
    ann9.coordinate = region9.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann9];

    MKCoordinateRegion region10 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region10.center.latitude = 39.952384;
    region10.center.longitude = -76.7253;
    region10.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region10.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview1 setRegion:region10 animated:YES];

    NewClass *ann10 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
    ann10.title = @"Vigil Location";
    ann10.subtitle = @"Planned Parenthood of York";
    ann10.coordinate = region10.center;
    [mapview1 addAnnotation:ann10];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Please try not to paste a wall of code.  It will turn off many potential answerers who do not want to read your entire block of code.  Please try to narrow down the problem to a smaller snippet of code

Answer (score 2):

You've set showsUserLocation but if you read the Apple docs you'll see that that function only turns on the blue dot, it doesn't zoom or pan the view. "http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation

What you want to do is set the user tracking mode to userfollows.

Other code tips:

- Put all those places in an array and loop over them, don't create them one at a time like that
- Don't setRegion on the map for every region you make. You're trying to get the map to zoom in on the user and each setRegion changes where the map is looking. Only the last one will have any effect anyway.
- You don't need to create a region just to get the coordinates for an annotation

Comment: Ok cool. How would the coding look for tracking the users location? 
Sorry Im really illiterate with xcode

Comment: It's pretty much what I said above `mapview1.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow`  ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/userTrackingMode